# Regarding IoT Plug and Play Preview

Tags: azure-iot-central

As IoT Plug and Play feature in Azure IoT Central is currently in Public Preview, when can we expect this feature to go GA.

Regards,
Vineet

Answer (score 0):

We currently don't have timelines that we can share externally. Check out the feed at the bottom of apps.azureiotcentral.com for the latest updates. 
-Luis (Product Manager @ Azure IoT Central)

Answer (score 0):

IoT Plug and Play is now fully supported in Azure IoT Central:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/internet-of-things/democratizing-iot-with-iot-plug-and-play-and-new-pricing-for/ba-p/1902762